# What is wrong with this Regular Expression?

Tags: regex

I am beginner and have some problems with regexp.

Input text is : something idUser=123654; nick="Tom" something

I need extract value of idUser -> 123456

I try this:

```
//idUser is already 8 digits number
        MatchCollection matchsID = Regex.Matches(pk.html, @"\bidUser=(\w{8})\b");
        Text = matchsID[1].Value;
```

but on output i get idUser=123654, I need only number

The second problem is with nick="Tom", how can I get only text Tom from this expresion.

Answer (score 1):

you don't show your output code, where you get the group from your match collection.

Hint: you will need group 1 and not group 0 if you want to have only what is in the parentheses.

Comment: Try `Text = matchsID[0].Groups[1].Value`

Answer (score 0):

```
.*?idUser=([0-9]+).*?
```

That regex should work for you :o)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pattern that should work:

```
\bidUser=(\d{3,8})\b|\bnick="(\w+)"
```

Given the input string:

```
something idUser=123654; nick="Tom" something
```

This yields 2 matches ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/w2y1n7gxwS)):

- First match is `User=123654`, group 1 captures `123654`
- Second match is `nick="Tom"`, group 2 captures `Tom`

Some variations:

- In .NET regex, you can also use named groups for better readability.
- If `nick` always appears after `idUser`, you can match the two at once instead of using alternation as above.
- I've used `{3,8}` repetition to show how to match at least 3 and at most 8 digits.

#### API links

- [`Match.Groups` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx)

  - This is how you get what individual groups captured in a match

Comment: I have problem with quotes in regexp .

MatchCollection matchsUsers = 
Regex.Matches
(pk.html, @"\bidUser=(\d{8})\b|\bnick="(\w+)""); 

How use " in \bnick="(\w+)"" ?

Comment: @Tom: in `@`-quoted string, you double `"` to escape it. So it becomes `@"\bidUser=(\d{8})\b|\bnick=""(\w+)"""`. Also, note that `\d{8}` only matches exactly 8 digits. Your example has `123456` which is only 6.

Answer (score 0):

Use [look-around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups/2973609#2973609)

```
(?<=idUser=)\d{1,8}(?=(;|$))
```

To fix length of digits to 6, use `(?<=idUser=)\d{6}(?=($|;))`